# Javascript move object key to parent object key

Tags: javascript, object

I have a question related to javascript objects.

I have an object like this:

```
const event = {
  title: 'some event',
  start: {
    date: '2019-04-16 12:33:04'
  }
}
```

You see that there is another object in the start key. Now my question; how can I move that value to just only the start key? So that i have something like this:

```
const event = {
  title: 'some event'
  start: '2019-04-16 12:33:04'
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT
I'm was not clear enough about my question:

So i have an api request with axios:

```
axios.get(url).then(res => {
  // The result is an array of objects and I want to map every start.date to just start
});
```

Comment: `event.start = event.start.date`

Answer (score 0):

Try reassign the *start* property with the child's *date* property.

```
event.start = event.start.date;
```

```js
const event = {
  title: 'some event',
  start: {
    date: '2019-04-16 12:33:04'
  }
}

event.start = event.start.date;
console.log(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple variable reassignment:

```js
const event = {
  title: "some event",
  start: {
    date: "2019-04-16 12:33:04"
  }
};

event.start = event.start.date;
console.log(event);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mutating the same object , I will rather suggest you to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and create a deep copy of it

```js
const event = {
  title: 'some event',
  start: {
    date: '2019-04-16 12:33:04'
  }
}


const newEvent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event));
newEvent.start = event.start.date;

console.log(newEvent)
```